# Programa que convierte un numero hexadecimal a decimal

Tags: c++

1. Validar si es una cadena hexadecimal o no.
2. Longitud maxima 10 caracteres.
3. Invertir numero hexadecimal ingresado y mostrar tambien su resultado.

Ésto es lo que llevo, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 75");
    char num[10];
    char n[10];
    char texto[4];
    int i, j, r, res, len, len2, hex = 0, hexa = 0, longitud;
    bool es_hexa;

    cout << " _____________________________________ " << endl;
    cout << "|_Programa_hecho_por_Equipo_3.1416TWO2|" << endl;
    cout << "Programa que convierte un numero hexadecimal cualquiera a su equivalente en decimal: \n" << endl;
    cout << "Ingresa numero Hexadecimal a convertir: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    len = strlen(num);
    longitud = strlen(num);
    cout << "\nSU LONGITUD ES: " << longitud << endl;

    es_hexa = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= longitud - 1; i++) {
        if (num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9') {
            char* texto1 = "ES HEXADECIMAL";
            strcpy(texto, texto1);
        }
        else {
            if (num[i] >= 'a' && num[i] <= 'f') {
                char* texto1 = "ES HEXADECIMAL";
                strcpy(texto, texto1);
            }
            else {
                if (num[i] >= 'A' && num[i] <= 'F') {
                    char* texto1 = "ES HEXADECIMAL";
                    strcpy(texto, texto1);
                } //IF
                else {
                    char* texto1 = "NO ES HEXADECIMAL";
                    strcpy(texto, texto1);
                    es_hexa = false;
                } //ELSE
                cout << "\nLA CADENA: " << texto << endl;
            } //FOR
            if (es_hexa) {
                char* texto1 = "ES HEXADECIMAL";
                strcpy(texto, texto1);
            } //IF
            else {
                char* texto1 = "NO ES HEXADECIMAL";
                strcpy(texto, texto1);
            }
            cout << "\nLA CADENA ES: " << texto << endl;

            for (i = 0; num[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                len--;
                if (num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9') {
                    r = num[i] - 48;
                }
                else {
                    if (num[i] >= 'a' && num[i] <= 'f') {
                        r = num[i] - 87;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (num[i] >= 'A' && num[i] <= 'F') {
                            r = num[i] - 55;
                        }
                    }
                }
                hex += r * pow(16, len);
            } //Fin for

            cout << "\nEL NUMERO " << num << " EN DECIMAL ES: " << hex << endl;

            cout << "\nEL NUMERO AL REVEZ ES: ";
            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                cout << num[j];
            }

            cout << "\n\nEL NUMERO " << n << " EN DECIMAL ES: " << endl;

            return 0;
        }
    }
} //Fin main
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con que es que necesitas ayuda? tu programa tira algun error?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

1. Puedes saber si una cadena de texto es un número hexadecimal, si al alimentar un [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) con esa cadena y leer un entero, se extraen todos los datos (llegas a `eof`):

   ```
   std::stringstream ss("fabada");
   int valor;
   ss >> std::hex >> valor;

   if (ss.eof())
       std::cout << "Es hexadecimal\n";
   ```

   La variable `valor` contendrá el resultado decimal del número hexadecimal.
2. Puedes saber si una cadena de texto tiene una longitud menor de 10 o menos caracteres, consultando su [`length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size):

   ```
   std::string cadena("En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no hace mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.");

   if (cadena.length() > 10)
       std::cout << "Es muy larga\n";
   ```
3. Puedes dar la vuelta a una cadena, copiándola al revés en otra:

   ```
   std::string palabra = "oido";
   std::string girada(palabra.rbegin(), palabra.rend()); // "odio"
   ```